# Excluding django form fields when condition met

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to exclude a form field from django forms when some conditions are met. Even when i supply valid conditions, the form renders without excluding the field.

here is what i am doing:

```
#views.py
def create_exam(request):
    cc = is_cc(request.user)
    form = ExamCreateForm(cc)
    return render(request, 'exam/exam_create.html', {'form': form})

#forms.py
class ExamCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, cc, *args, **kwargs):
        if cc:
            self.Meta.exclude.append('section')
        super(ExamCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta(object):
        model = Exam
        exclude = []
```

Even when the `cc` is `True` the form still renders the `section` field.

Where am i making mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ExamCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, cc, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExamCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if cc:
            del self.fields['section']
```

Comment: tried already, it returns: 'ExamCreateForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

Comment: I already tried all possible things which i was able to find on SO, it still throws errors. `'ExamCreateForm'` object has no attribute `'fields'`

Comment: As i said, i tried all possible hacks, it still doesn't work. Most  probably something is wrong with the `__init__` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87530/discussion-between-ajay-gupta-and-v1k45).