# Django : How do we automatically hide the parts of a form that requests information that we have already entered?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Saying that, I have two classes (service and product) which are linked with a foreign key. Each class contains a number of forms.
I want that each information entered in the form of the product class is no longer requested in the form of the service class and if it has detected it I want to hide the fields which request it in the template! (to avoid repetition)
Do you have a method for doing this pleaaaaaase?
Product :
model.py

```
class Product :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    length = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
```

Service :
model.py

```
class Service :
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,  blank=True)
```

Comment: Could we see your forms.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically remove form fields by overriding it's `init` method in the forms.py.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32128961/4618758